# How to use the Quarkus Runtime Class Loader

Tags: runtime, classloader, quarkus, graalvm, graalvm-native-image

I need to dynamically load class or jar files into our Quarkus project at *runtime*. We are using GraalVM and native images in our project.

I have found the [Runtime Class Loader](https://quarkus.io/guides/class-loading-reference#classloader-implementations) implementation. But I didn't find any example or detailed information about how to use this.

How to use this class loader and load jars/class files at runtime (within Quarkus + native images)? Or is there any documentation about it somewhere?

Comment: Have you tried `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().loadClass()`?

Comment: Yes. But, sorry, my question was not precise enough. We use Quarkus in combination with native images, and I couldn't find a way to load classes when the classes to load are not known at build time. Do you have any idea how to do that?

Comment: Have a look at https://quarkus.io/guides/writing-native-applications-tips#registering-for-reflection